# Is a question about network analysis via mean-field theory type approaches on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, migration

TCS seems to study networks, but I seldom see mean-field theory approaches (which come from statistical-mechanics) used by computer scientists. Hence, I am unsure if the following question from the closing TP.SE can be migrated here:

[Refinements of pair approximation for network analysis](http://theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/q/52/57)

On the one hand, it is talking about approximating the dynamics of agents in a network (something TCS would study) and is motivated by evolutionary game theory which is sometimes lumped into algorithmic game theory. On the other hand, it is kind of a statistical-mechanics question. Although physics and computer science often touch at statistical-mechanics, I am not sure of where to draw the line.

If the question is on-topic here, then I would prefer to migrate it here over math.SE, stats.SE, physics.SE, or one of the other likely targets.

**Is the question on-topic?**

Comment: I think it would be fine.